# Need Callback When more page load in Pagedlist Android

Tags: android, paging, android-paging

I have Implemented the RecyclerView with PagedList. As per Documentation

```
The Paging Library's key component is the PagedList class, which loads chunks of your app's data, or pages. As more data is needed, it's paged into the existing PagedList object. If any loaded data changes, a new instance of PagedList is emitted to the observable data holder from a LiveData or RxJava2-based object.
```

So observable will get notified when new instance of PagedList will generate but I want to know(Via callback or some other way) when next page or next batch of data load into PagedList. I will explain through one example.
Suppose I have 40 item in my local database and page size is 20. So First 20 Data will be loaded into PagedList and I'll get this list via Livedata But for next 20 item I am not getting information/No information.
I want to do some work when next batch of data loads.

Comment: cannot you simply observe list size for that

Comment: Strugglling for the same problem